# Have Gravity Form inputs show on different modals

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm trying to make a new single form which would be the first/last name and then the next modal after button click will be the email and form submission. On form submission it wouldn't reload the page but just display none to the modal. I set it up to where the landing form has the first/last then a dummy button that gets rid of the landing form but not sure how to bring back the 3rd input (the email) and the finish button where it'll work fully. Thoughts?

```
//calls the whole gravity form. I displayed none to the email input and submit button

<?php echo do_shortcode('[gravityform id=3]') ?>     


//  Made a div of the input fields that were displayed none. Put them in modal 2 manually and displayed them here.


<div id="email-button">
<li style="display:block;" id="field_3_3" class="gfield gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible">
  <label class="gfield_label" for="input_3_3">Email<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label>
   <div class="ginput_container ginput_container_text"><div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
  <input name="input_3" id="input_3_3" type="text" value="" class="medium" placeholder="Email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
 </div>
</div>
</li>
</div>

// continue button, but only want it to display none a modal after submission. 

<div style="display:block;" class="gform_footer top_label"> 
<div class="ui-btn ui-input-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
Continue
 <input type="submit" id="gform_submit_button_3" class="gform_button button btn btn-default" value="Continue" 
onclick="if(window[&quot;gf_submitting_3&quot;]){return false;}  
window[&quot;gf_submitting_3&quot;]=true;  " 
onkeypress="if( event.keyCode == 13 ){ if(window[&quot;gf_submitting_3&quot;]){return false;} 
window[&quot;gf_submitting_3&quot;]=true;  
jQuery(&quot;#gform_3&quot;).trigger(&quot;submit&quot;,[true]); }">
</div> 
</div>
```